# chrome javascript input not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having some trouble with the current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( window.addEventListener ) {  
  var state = 0, konami = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];  
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {  
    if ( e.keyCode == konami[state] ) state++;  
    else state = 0;  
    if ( state == 10 )
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.style.width = "1px";
      div.style.height = "1px";
      div.innerHTML = '<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/goQP8qiOtuo&list=PLFA793D3BC19E3221?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1" width="100%" height="100%">';
      document.body.appendChild(div);
    }, true);  
}  
</script>
```

The code used to work, and then suddenly stopped. I believe it's to do with my computer, as it doesn't work on Chrome or IE.
I've tested it on a different PC and it works fine there.

I'm not sure what the problem is, and I've done a lot of searching and found nothing.
If anyone here has an answer, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Given that the last if block is missing brackets altogether, I very much doubt that there is any browser or PC where this would work.

Comment: Your `if` statement block needs `{ }` around it.

Comment: I've just found out it's not a problem with the code, and is enfact a problem with my PC (I have no idea what yet).
Other websites with a similar Konami Code Easter-Egg have stopped working as well (Like Buzzfeed and Vogue).

Comment: And I will fix my if statement and check that :)

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd `if` statement needs `{}` to execute a block of code if succeeds.

```
if ( window.addEventListener ) {  
  var state = 0, konami = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];  
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {  
    if ( e.keyCode == konami[state] ) state++;  
    else state = 0;  
    if ( state == 10 ) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.style.width = "1px";
      div.style.height = "1px";
      div.innerHTML = '<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/goQP8qiOtuo&list=PLFA793D3BC19E3221?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1" width="100%" height="100%">';
      document.body.appendChild(div);
  }
    }, true);  
}
```